# Prisma orderBy before take

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, prisma

I'm making a query in Prisma to get the first 100 items sorted by orderBy `desc`. I want Prisma to return the items with the highest amount, so orderBy first and then get the first 100. Instead, Prisma is getting the first 100 items and then ordering just those.

Here's my query:

```
      prisma.random.findMany({
        where: { text: { in: texts }},
        skip: 0,
        take: 100,
        orderBy: {
          amount: 'desc'
        },
      });
```